# Refactoring with core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I've started learning core.logic and I'm totally lost. I am trying to write a core.logic relation which refactors an expression, renaming symbols. I want a relation that returns for a given expression, list of symbols and a list of symbols to rename those symbols:

```
(defn rename [exp from to]...
```

the expression with all the symbols in from becoming the corresponding one in to:

```
e.g. (rename '(defn multiply [x y] (* x y)) [x y] [a b])
```

returns `(defn multiply [a b] (* a b))`

but it needs to be aware of scope,

so `(rename '(defn q [x] ((fn [x] (* x 5)) x)) [x] [a])`

would return `(defn q [a] ((fn [x] (* x 5)) a))`

I don't know where to start solving this - any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you more interested in solving the problem, or using core.logic to solve it? I could point to another solution.

Comment: I could do it functionally, but I want to see how to do it relationally, out of curiosity - unless that's a stupid way of doing it! Any suggestions are welcome. Truth is, having tried a few simple exercises in core.logic, I still have no idea how to approach this problem (which is a real problem I need to solve for a thing I'm writing), in a relational way. I thought it looked like a candidate for core.logic

Comment: Here is some code for hygienic transformation. https://github.com/frenchy64/analyze/blob/master/src/analyze/hygienic.clj It wouldn't be hard to update it to rename locals. This works on fully macroexpanded forms. It would be pretty much impossible to get it correctly working without fully macroexpanding.

Comment: thanks for the code - although with my 1 year of Clojure, it's basically from the future. Must learn macros...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is more suitable for FP as it is just a tree traversal and replace operation, where as LP is more about specifying constrains and asking all possible solution around those constrains for a specific input. But if you really want to do this logical way, I tried something that does try to do it LP way but it doesn't handle a lot of cases and is just a starting point.

```
(defrel replace-with a b)
(fact replace-with 'x 'a)
(fact replace-with 'y 'b)

(defn replace [a b]
   (conde
    [(replace-with a b)]
    [(== a b)]))


(defn replace-list [from to]
  (conde 
   [(== from []) (== to [])]
   [(fresh [f t f-rest t-rest]
            (resto from f-rest)
            (resto to t-rest)
            (firsto from f) (firsto to t)  
            (conda [(replace-list f t)]
                   [(replace f t)])
            (replace-list f-rest t-rest))]))


(first (run 1 [q]
        (fresh [from]
        (== from '(defn multiply [x y] (* x y)))
        (replace-list from q))))

==> (defn multiply (a b) (* a b))
```